# ggplot display geom_segment as a sequence of points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display some data, where I don't only need to display a point using `geom_point`, but also want to trace a line to it from the axis. I figured I can do it with `geom_segment`, but I want to display a sequence of discrete dots instead.

Say I have a data like this:

```
df2 <- data_frame(x = c("a", "b", "c" ,"d"), y = c(3:6))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
      x     y
  <chr> <int>
1     a     3
2     b     4
3     c     5
4     d     6
```

What I want to get is like the graph below, only having a dot in each of 4 variables between 0 and their value (with the desired points marked manually in red):

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x)) + geom_point(aes(y=y)) + geom_point(aes(y=0))
```

[image]

Comment: Variation on a theme: `library(dplyr) ; df2 %>% group_by(x) %>% do(data.frame(y = 0:.$y)) %>% mutate(c = y %in% range(y)) %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = c)) + geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + scale_colour_manual(values = c('red', 'black'))`

Comment: or in base, `ggplot(do.call(rbind, lapply(apply(df2, 1, function(r){data.frame(x = r[1], y = 0:r[2])}), function(d){cbind(d, c = d$y %in% range(d$y))})), aes(x, y, colour = c)) + geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + scale_colour_manual(values = c('red', 'black'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works... you could wrap it up in a function to make it more generalizable if needed.

First we use `expand.grid` to create all combinations of `x` and `1:(max(y) - 1)`, join it to the original data, and filter out the unnecessary ones.

```
library(dplyr)
df3 = left_join(expand.grid(x = unique(df2$x), i = 1:max(df2$y - 1)),
          df2) %>%
    filter(i < y)
```

Once the data is constructed, the plotting is easy:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=y)) + 
    geom_point(y = 0) +
    geom_point(data = df3, aes(y = i), color = "red") +
    expand_limits(y = 0)
```

[image]

I'm not sure if you actually want the dots to be red - if you want them to all look the same then you could use `1:max(df2$y)` (omit the `-1`) and use `<=` in the filter to and then only use the resulting data frame.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use a data.table approach, using a similar expansion methodology you could use:

```
dt <- setDT(df2)
dt_expand<-dt[rep(seq(nrow(dt)),dt$y),]
dt_expand[,y2:=(1:.N),by=.(x)]
ggplot(dt_expand, aes(x=x)) + geom_point(aes(y=y2)) + geom_point(aes(y=0))
```

Note I didn't include the red coloring, but that is easily done if you want it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution in base R. The idea is to create 2 different datasets , one for red points:

```
dat1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y)data.frame(x=x,y=seq(0,y)),df2$x,df2$y))
```

And another for the black points

```
dat2 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y)data.frame(x=x,y=c(0,y)),df2$x,df2$y))
```

Then the plot is just the juxtopsition of 2 layers of the same plot  but with different datas:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=dat1,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point(col="red") +
  geom_point(data=dat2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, which is similar to @Gregor's, in that it's creating a new data vector.

```
d <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c" ,"d"), y = c(3:6))

new_points <- mapply(seq, 0, d$y)
new <- data.frame(new = unlist(lapply(new_points, as.data.frame)), 
                     x = rep(letters[1:4], d$y + 1),
                     group = 1)

d <- merge(d, new, by = "x")
d$group <- as.factor(ifelse(d$y == d$new|d$new == 0, 2, d$group))

ggplot(d, aes(x, new, color = group)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]